# java command line flyway migration

Tags: java, flyway

I did following steps for command line java migration:

1. create java file

```java
package db.migration;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class V1_0_1_1210__Test implements JdbcMigration{

    @Override
     public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {
        //add insert stmt
    }

}
```

2. create jar of it  V1_0_1_1210_TEST.jar and added into `{flyway location}\jars` folder.
3. set `flyway.locations=classpath:db.migration` into conf file in flyway

When I execute migrate commad, it throw Warning like

> WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration

Please check below attached image, it is actually jar. that I have extracted for more info.

[image]

Comment: I think normal folder structure `db/migration` without classpath is sufficient.

Comment: If you don't defined classpath, that is bydefault. I have removed but still same error

Comment: Hm, I think flyway looks for sql scripts in the resources folder, so I'm not sure if it finds the class in the source folder. Does the command work without flyway?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a Spring JDBC migration and not just a plain Jdbc migration you will also need the Spring JDBC jar and its dependencies in the `<flyway-install-dir>/jars` folder.

Comment: Kindly check updated question. I remove spring jdbc migration. still it does not work. could you tell me what needs to provide into classpath. it does not resolve classpath issue yet

Comment: thanks. I am not getting you. as I have used plain jdbc migration now. but I face issue relation to classpath not found.